# Custom List Template is not being pulled by SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates()

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate

I am adding custom lists programmaticaly from a custom template.  I check to see if the custom list template exists, and if not I create the list template by creating a list and then saving it as a template using the SPList.SaveAsTemplate() method.  However, during the same timer job, I try to get the list template, but it doesn't show in the SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates() method.  It does however show in the UI under the List Template Gallery.  Any idea as to why it would show in the UI but not be returned in the method call?

Comment: Just to verify.  You have a timer job and within that job you are creating a list template and then trying to retrieve that template at some other location within the same job?

Comment: Correct.  I was making multiple sites and wanted to create the template initially and then retrieve it for the following sites.  I finally just took the whole template out of the equation and created the list each time from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635129/sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution-uploaded-stp-files-to-catalogs-lt-using-featu/9331694#9331694). With that you should get a result from GetCustomListTemplates instead of just an empty list.